# FormResponse.GetId() returning incorrect response ID?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to set up a webhook for my Google form and all was well until I tried retrieving the ID of the response to use in a URL like so:

```js
function onSubmit(e) {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var allResponses = form.getResponses();
    var latestResponse = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
    var formID = "top-secret";
    var link = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/" + formID + "/edit#response=" + latestResponse.getId();
}
```

I have checked the Google Apps Script documentation and it looks like [getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getId()) is what I am after here. The issue with this is that the ID I get from this is incorrect. When I try to visit the link with this ID, I get `Response not found`.

**getId()** returns `2_ABaOnufCTeHiCWUFr0VRcCb8wkiWIZzeIZQU0xyP5pppD7oSr3nPFQ4y8VdOA96dYU_5Ros` for example whereas the actual response ID from the form itself returns `ACYDBNiLhfYgdxvkakafdps42HYuaZYkU-LrsjBtvt9ABhzal71zZWZnNsTxHVTrm6gom_E`.

Do I need to do some conversion to make this work or is there some other function I should be using instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought that in the current stage, unfortunately, the value of `responseId` of `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/{formId}/edit#response={responseId}` cannot be retrieved by Google Forms service. [Rer](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms) So in this case, it is required to use several workarounds.

#### Workaround 1:

It uses `getEditResponseUrl()`. When this method is used, the following URL is obtained.

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/{ID1}/viewform?edit2={ID2}
```

- In this case, `ID1` is not the form ID. `ID2` is the same with the ID retrieved by `latestResponse.getId()` in your script.
- When your script is used, you can retrieve this URL by `latestResponse.getEditResponseUrl()`.

#### Workaround 2:

It uses `toPrefilledUrl()`. When this method is used, the following URL is obtained.

```
    https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/{ID1}/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.###=###&entry.###=###,,,
```

- In this case, `ID1` is not the form ID. And, each value is given by `entry.###=###`.
- When your script is used, you can retrieve this URL by `latestResponse.toPrefilledUrl()`.

### Updated at March 16, 2022:

#### Workaround 3:

In this workaround, Google Forms API is used. Google Forms API has published a stable as the generally-available v1. [Ref](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/03/google-forms-api-generally-available.html)

In the current stage, the endpoint changed from `https://forms.googleapis.com/v1beta/forms/` to `https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/`. And, you can also use Forms API without joining to "Early Adopter Program".

But, as an important point, in order to use Forms API, it is required to link Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project. In the current stage, Google Forms API cannot be used with Advanced Google services. So please link Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project. Ref And also, please enable Google Forms API at API console. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/Linking-Google-Cloud-Platform-Project-to-Google-Apps-Script-Project-for-New-IDE)

When Google Forms API is used, your goal can be directly achieved. In this case, "Method: forms.responses.list" is used.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const formId = "###"; // Please set your Form ID.

  const url = `https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/${formId}/responses?fields=*&pageSize=5000`;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
  const obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  const sorted = obj.responses.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.lastSubmittedTime).getTime() > new Date(b.lastSubmittedTime).getTime() ? -1 : 1);
  const responseId = sorted[0].responseId; // This is the value you expect.

  const link = `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/${formId}/edit#response=${responseId}`;
  console.log(link)
}
```

- In this case, `formId` is the form ID. And, the retrieved value of `responseId` is the response ID of the last response.
- In this case, as a sample, `pageSize=5000` is used. When more responses are existing, please use `pageToken`.
- The scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.responses.readonly` is used in this method.

#### References:

- [getEditResponseUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#geteditresponseurl)
- [toPrefilledUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#toprefilledurl)
- [Method: forms.responses.list](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms.responses/list)
- [Create surveys, quizzes, and more using the Google Forms API, now generally available](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/03/google-forms-api-generally-available.html)

Comment: I tested all three of these and found that none of them really achieved what I was after. The first workaround simply linked to an edit post which isn't what I am trying to do. The second workaround seemed to have just sent me to the actual form entry page, which isn't what I am after either. The third workaround I tested but got some authentication issues. `Request failed for https://forms.googleapis.com returned code 403.`

Comment: @Venk Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About workaround 3, in this case, it is required to join in "Early Adopter Program". Please check it. And, if you have already joined and you can use Google Forms API, in this case, please include the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.responses.readonly`. When I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. I confirmed that your goal can be achieved using Forms API. I deeply apologize when I tested my sample script, no error occurs. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Venk At March 16, 2022, Google Forms API has published a stable as the generally-available v1. [Ref](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/03/google-forms-api-generally-available.html) So, in the current stage, you can achieve your goal using Forms API by linking Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project. Please check it.